# Navigating to a page 2 URL in selenium

Tags: selenium, url, selenium-webdriver, url-routing

I am trying to navigate to this link using selenium selenium:

https://www.pwccmarketplace.com/market-price-research?q=upper%20deck%20auston%20matthews%20rc%20young%20guns%20psa%2010&year_min=2004&year_max=2019&price_min=50&price_max=10000&sort_by=date_desc&sale_type=auction&items_per_page=250&page=2

Its a page 2 of a search query. But when it open it up in a new browser, the results shows the results of page 1 in the search query. Is there anyway I can overcome this and get the page 2 results when I open it in a new browser?

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: On clicking the URL manually also, it is redirecting the user to first page. Can you check if there are any documents on the APIs and to get any specific page? If it's there, you can use the URL that will directly take you to second page. Else, i think you need to add an extra step to navigate to second page.

Comment: Startswith page 1 : `https://www.pwccmarketplace.com/market-price-research?q=upper%20deck%20auston%20matthews%20rc%20young%20guns%20psa%2010&year_min=2004&year_max=2019&price_min=50&price_max=10000&sort_by=date_desc&sale_type=auction&items_per_page=250&page=1` this will redirect to page 1 and then increment page number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i use driver.get twice then it takes me to 2nd page. Please check and let me know whether this helps or not.
2nd time it redirects me to correct page.

```
driver.get("https://www.pwccmarketplace.com/market-price-research?q=upper%20deck%20auston%20matthews%20rc%20young%20guns%20psa%2010&year_min=2004&year_max=2019&price_min=50&price_max=10000&sort_by=date_desc&sale_type=auction&items_per_page=250&page=2");
driver.get("https://www.pwccmarketplace.com/market-price-research?q=upper%20deck%20auston%20matthews%20rc%20young%20guns%20psa%2010&year_min=2004&year_max=2019&price_min=50&price_max=10000&sort_by=date_desc&sale_type=auction&items_per_page=250&page=2");
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to get it to redirect to the correct page the first time any chance?

Comment: You have to check with your development team about this behavior.They will let you know the reason for redirecting to 1st page.If it is an issue with application,you can ask developers to fix it

Comment: Looks like This is an issue with your application and nothing to do with selenium.